# Visual studio deploys wrong file

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, .net-standard, windowsiot

I have raspberry PI project on Windows IoT which have one main UWP app and couple .NET Standard 2.0 assemblies. Couple of assemblies have reference to HTTPnet nuget and this nuget internally have version for full framework, UWP and .NET Standard. In Visual studio when I expand Dependencies for HTTPnet it shows everywhere that it is using .NET standard but after deploy and run I have exception that HTTPnet.Netstandard.dll file is not found. After investigating RPI filesystem I noticed that deployed dll is HTTPnet.UniversalWindows.dll and HTTPnet.Netstandard.dll is missing. 
The question is how to force using .net standard on deploy?

For now I added HTTPnet.Netstandard.dll to my UWP references but this is not good solution in long terms.

Comment: What version of .net standard are you using? 1.x? or 2.0? I think the issue is that `HTTPnet.Netstandard.dll` is likely not a real library and is just a placeholder for .net standard. Since .net standard is essentially just a "contract" it creates these files so that when it runs it knows which real dll to use(.net framework, .net core, etc). I think a lot of these issues go away with .net standard 2 though. I assume the issue you're having though is that when you publish it just thinks its a uwp app so just copies the actual uwp dlls

Comment: I'm using .NET Standard 2.0

Comment: Are you sure your raspberry pi has the correct framework installed to support .net standard 2?

Comment: https://youtu.be/vg6nR7hS2lI?t=5m34s if you watch this it explains that the issue is that netstandard.dll should be coming from your framework, not bundled into your application

Comment: My PI have version 10.0.16299.192 and UWP have Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform 6.06 so they support .NET Standard 2.0. I watched video but don’t know what you suggest me to do?

Comment: I have added nuget to UWP and now both dll's are deployed

Comment: Try to update Visual Studio. Build Tools of earlier versions could behave differently.

Comment: I Have 15.5.5 - only newer is 15.6 but it is in beta